# Application not running when i changed the bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have changed the bundle identifier of the application. When i tried to run it then it is just building successfully not running . I have tried by restarting the simulator. Please suggest some solution

Comment: Close Xcode then open & try....

Comment: I suppose this is not the problem.Try cleaning it and then building it (or) quit xcode and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running your app on **simulator** then changes in **Bundle Identifier** will not affect your running state, changes will only affect when you are running your app on **device**.

But make one thing sure, **Bundle Identifier** must not be blank , just type something in it.